# How to sync data from a local database to a remote database

Tags: java, database

I have a java application that collects data (such as login user, logon time, ...) into a local database (probably a Derby database or similar). This application will run on several PCs (windows XP, 7 ...). I would like to collect all data from each PC and save into a main database that reside on a remote server. Then a web application could display the results and statistics for all PCs. The local database is important as we need to collect data even if the link to the main servers database is down.

I would like to be able to push the data from each PCs to the main database. (notice that this ideas come from the splunk application where log entries are push from local applications to a main server).

1. How can the java application of each PCs communicate with the main database. Any good examples are welcomed?
2. Is it possible to use some HTTP request (json or rest) from the local java application to send the data? If so, how can this be done (examples)? What is needed on the local PCs to accomplish this?

Any better ideas or suggestion are welcomed.

Comment: Sorry, this question seems way too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: If network firewall allows you could always connect to the main database directly from your java application (similar as you are connecting to Derby) and push the records directly.  If that's not an option, I'd look into standing up a web service that your client can push data to, and that web service would write records to your master DB.

Answer (score 1):

> How can the java application of each PCs communicate with the main
>   database.

Whatever method you're using to communicate with your derby database will be the same to communicate with your remote database.  Typically this would be done with JPA or Hibernate or a similar ORM library.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html

> Is it possible to use some HTTP request (json or rest) from the local
>   java application to send the data? If so, how can this be done
>   (examples)? What is needed on the local PCs to accomplish this?

For this you'd want to investigate JAX-RS which is the java standard way of communicating with restful web services.

See: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html